# How to use awk to find a char in a string in bash

Tags: bash, awk

I have a `char` variable called `sign` and a given string `sub`. I need to find out how many times this `sign` appears in the `sub` and cannot use `grep`.

For example:

```
sign = c

sub = mechanic cup cat

echo "$sub" | awk <code i am asking for> | wc -l
```

And the output should be `4` because `c` appears 4 times. What should be inside <>?

Comment: After removing the whitespace around `=`, have a look at this https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#String-Functions If using wc is acceptable, you could delete every char except `c` from `sub` and count the bytes of the output.

Answer (score 5):

```
sign=c
sub='mechanic cup cat'

echo "$sub" |
  awk -v sign="$sign" -F '' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){if ($i==sign) cnt++}} END{print cnt}'
```

---

**Edit:**

Changes for the requirements in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61354441/how-to-use-awk-to-find-a-char-in-a-string-in-bash/61354707#comment108540106_61354707):

1. Test if the length of `sign` is 1 (no `=` present). If true, change `sign` and `sub` to lowercase to ignore the case.
2. Use `${sign:0:1}` to only pass the first character to `awk`.

```
sign=c
sub='mechanic Cup cat'

if [ "${#sign}" -eq 1 ]; then
  sign=${sign,,}
  sub=${sub,,}
fi

echo "$sub" |
  awk -v sign="${sign:0:1}" -F '' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){if ($i==sign) cnt++}} END{print cnt}'
```

Comment: It works! Thank you! Now, the input is taken from the terminal, so basically it isn't static, i use ```read -r sign``` and there are two options, it can be a char, which works well, or it can be for example ```c=```. 
Let's say ```sub="mechanic Cup cat"```. If ```sign``` is ```c``` it count both C and c so the output is 4. If ```sign``` is ```c=``` it counts only the exact char, so not both c and C, but only c, ale in this case the output is 3. I used ```if [[ $sign =~ "=" ]];``` and ```grep``` but then i realised i cannot use it. What should i add to awk to make it works?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

A combination of Quasimodo's comment and Freddy's lower-case example:

```
$ sign=c
$ sub='mechanic Cup cat'
```

---

A `tr` + `wc` solution if `${sign}` is a single character.

Count the number of times `${sign}` shows up in `${sub}`, ignoring case:

```
$ tr -cd [${sign,,}] <<< ${sub,,} | wc -c
4
```

Where:

- `${sign,,}` & `{sub,,}` - convert to all lowercase
- `tr -cd [...]` - find all characters listed inside the brackets (`[]`), `-d` says to delete/remove said characters while `-c` says to take the complement (ie, remove all but the characters in the brackets), so `-cp [${sign,,]` says to remove all but the character stored in `${sign}`
- `<<< ....` - here string (allows passing a variable/string in as an argument to `tr`
- `wc -c` count the number of chracers

NOTE: This only works if `${sign}` contains a single character.

---

A `sed` solution that should work regardless of the number of characters in `${sign}`.

```
$ sub='mechanic Cup cat'
```

First we embed a new line character before each occurrence of `${sign,,}`:

```
$ sign=c
$ sed "s/\(${sign,,}\)/\n\1/g" <<< ${sub,,}
me
chani
c
cup
cat

$ sign=cup
$ sed "s/\(${sign,,}\)/\n\1/g" <<< ${sub,,}
mechanic
cup cat
```

Where:

- `\(${sign,,}\)` - find the pattern that matches `${sign}` (all lowercase) and assign to position `1`
- `\n\1` - place a newline (`\n`) in the stream just before our pattern in position 1

At this point we just want the lines that start with `${sign,,}`, which is where `tail +2` comes into play (ie, display lines 2 through n):

```
$ sign=c
$ sed "s/\(${sign,,}\)/\n\1/g" <<< ${sub,,} | tail +2
chani
c
cup
cat

$ sign=cup
$ sed "s/\(${sign,,}\)/\n\1/g" <<< ${sub,,} | tail +2
cup cat
```

And now we pipe to `wc -l` to get a line count (ie, count the number of times `${sign}` shows up in `${sub}` - ignoring case):

```
$ sign=c
$ sed "s/\(${sign,,}\)/\n\1/g" <<< ${sub,,} | tail +2 | wc -l
4

$ sign=cup
$ sed "s/\(${sign,,}\)/\n\1/g" <<< ${sub,,} | tail +2 | wc -l
1
```